# PHP Insert data in database from array and output db data in html table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having a problem with inserting data in my MySQL db table from an array. I have a form and an array which stores submitted values and its contents I display in a html table. In each table row there are values from one submit and a button which deletes the row with jQuery. 
The problem is I also need the functionality to select a row from the html table and insert in my database table. I would like a button on each row's end that when clicked would insert the rows contents in my database table, similar to what i have now with deleting a row from my html table. 
Deleting can be done with simple jQuery, but with this I have no idea how to continue, thanks for answers in advance.

This is how far i have gotten:

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-7"> <!-- array table col -->

            <div class="arraytable" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top:15px;">

                <table id="arraytable" class="table table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Code:</th>
                        <th>Title:</th>
                        <th>Inventory nr.:</th>
                        <th>Inventory value.:</th>
                        <th>Retail value.:</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <?php

                    session_start();
                    $code = $title = $number = $value = $retailValue = "";
                    $code_err = $number_err = $value_err = $title_err = $retailValue_err = "";

                    if( isset($_POST["add"]) ){

                        if( empty(trim($_POST["code"]))  ){
                            $code_err = "Enter code.";
                        }
                        else{
                            $code = trim($_POST["code"]);
                        }

                        if ( empty(trim($_POST["title"]))  ) {
                            $title_err = "Enter title.";
                        }
                        else {
                            $title = trim($_POST["title"]);
                        }

                        if ( empty(trim($_POST["number"])) || !is_numeric($_POST["number"])  ) {
                            $number_err = "Inventory nr. must be entered, must be numeric";
                        }
                        else{
                            $number = trim($_POST["number"]);
                        }
                        if ( empty(trim($_POST["value"])) || !is_numeric($_POST["value"]) ) {
                            $value_err = "Inventory value  must be entered, must be numeric";
                        }
                        else {
                            $value = trim($_POST["value"]);
                        }

                        if ( empty(trim($_POST["retailvalue"])) || !is_numeric($_POST["retailvalue"]) || $_POST["retailvalue"] < $_POST["value"] ) {
                            $retailValue_err = " Retail value must be entered, must be numeric. Must be smaller than inventory value.";
                        }
                        else {
                            $retailValue = trim($_POST["retailvalue"]);
                        }

                        if(empty($code_err) && empty($number_err) && empty($value_err) && empty($title_err) && empty($retailValue_err)) {

                            $_SESSION['info'][] = array($code, $title, $number, $value, $retailValue);


                            if(isset($_SESSION['info'])) {
                                for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['info']); $i++) {
                                    echo "<tr> <td></td>";
                                    foreach($_SESSION['info'][$i] as $key){

                                        echo " <td>$key</td>";

                                    }

                                    echo "<td><a class=\"remove\" href=\"\"> <i class=\"fa fa-trash\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> </a></td> ";
                                    echo "</tr>";

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end arraytable col -->

        <div class="col-3" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- form colum -->

            <form name="form" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "POST">

                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($code_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Code:" id="code" name="code"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $code; ?>"/>
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $code_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($title_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Title:" id="title" name="title"  class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $title_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($number_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Inventory nr:" id="number" name="number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $number_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($value_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Inventory value:" id="value" name="value" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $value_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($retailValue_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Retail value:" id="retailvalue" name="retailvalue" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $retailValue; ?>" />
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $retailValue_err; ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" id="add"  value="Add" >
                </div>
            </form>

        </div> <!-- end form colum -->
</div> <!-- end array table, form row -->

<script>
    $('#arraytable').on('click','tr a.remove',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this

```
if(empty($code_err) && empty($number_err) && empty($value_err) && empty($title_err) && empty($retailValue_err)) {
    // insert all inputs to an a new array
    $newInfo = array($_POST['code'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['number'], $_POST['value'], $_POST['retailvalue']);
    // push the new array to session variable 'info'
    array_push($_SESSION['info'], $newInfo);
    // as you already have, loop thru each session info
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['info']); $i++) {
        echo "<tr><td></td>";
        // echo each value to table cells
        foreach($_SESSION['info'][$i] as $value){
           echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><a class=\"remove\" href=\"\"> <i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>Delete</a></td> ";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Plus the condition for checking error on retail value is wrong if you want it to be smaller than inventory value. Please double check

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this give me an error array_push excepts parameter 1 to be array, null given. Also how can could I insert each submit values from the array to my DB table? For example one submit consists of values 1,2,3,4,5 i would need those values to be stored in one row of my DB table

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Ajax to post the data to Database.
You could see that I used javascript method called postToDatabase to post the data and the data has been passed as arguments to the method.

Check out the code below.

```
            <?php
            // your database connection and database selection using PDO ( Safe and better to use PDO)
            //BEGINNING OF DATABASE CONNECTION
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "password";
            $db_name = "db";
            $db_engine = 'mysql';

            try {
                $conn = new PDO("$db_engine:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                { echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); }
                    // END OF DATABSE CONNECTION


            //DATA POSTED VIA AJAX
             $code = trim($_POST["code"]);
             $title = trim($_POST["title"]);
             $number = trim($_POST["number"]);
             $value = trim($_POST["value"]);
             $retailValue = trim($_POST["retailvalue"]);

             // BEGINNING OF INSERT QUERY
             $sql = $conn ->prepare("INSERT INTO books (code, title, number, value, retailvalue) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); // ? WILL BE REPLACED BY THEIR RESPECTIVE VALUES IN THE EXEC() METHOD.
             $sql->execute(array($code, $title, $number, $value, $retailValue));


            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title></title>
                 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div id="success_msg" class="alert alert-success fade in" style="display:none;">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Data Saved.
            </div>
                    <div class="col-7"> <!-- array table col -->

                        <div class="arraytable" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top:15px;">

                            <form name="form">
                            <table id="arraytable" class="table table-hover">
                                <tbody>
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Code:</th>
                                    <th>Title:</th>
                                    <th>Inventory nr.:</th>
                                    <th>Inventory value.:</th>
                                    <th>Retail value.:</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <?php

                                session_start();
                                $code = $title = $number = $value = $retailValue = "";
                                $code_err = $number_err = $value_err = $title_err = $retailValue_err = "";

                                if( isset($_POST["add"]) ){

                                    if( empty(trim($_POST["code"]))  ){
                                        $code_err = "Enter code.";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        $code = trim($_POST["code"]);
                                    }

                                    if ( empty(trim($_POST["title"]))  ) {
                                        $title_err = "Enter title.";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $title = trim($_POST["title"]);
                                    }

                                    if ( empty(trim($_POST["number"])) || !is_numeric($_POST["number"])  ) {
                                        $number_err = "Inventory nr. must be entered, must be numeric";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        $number = trim($_POST["number"]);
                                    }
                                    if ( empty(trim($_POST["value"])) || !is_numeric($_POST["value"]) ) {
                                        $value_err = "Inventory value  must be entered, must be numeric";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $value = trim($_POST["value"]);
                                    }

                                    if ( empty(trim($_POST["retailvalue"])) || !is_numeric($_POST["retailvalue"]) || $_POST["retailvalue"] < $_POST["value"] ) {
                                        $retailValue_err = " Retail value must be entered, must be numeric. Must be smaller than inventory value.";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $retailValue = trim($_POST["retailvalue"]);
                                    }

                                    if(empty($code_err) && empty($number_err) && empty($value_err) && empty($title_err) && empty($retailValue_err)) {

                                        $_SESSION['info'][] = array($code, $title, $number, $value, $retailValue);

                                        if(isset($_SESSION['info'])) {
                                            for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['info']); $i++) {
                                                echo "<tr> <td></td>";
                                                foreach($_SESSION['info'][$i] as $key){

                                                    echo " <td>$key</td>";
                                                    $vals .=  "'$key',";
                                                }

                                                echo "<td><a class=\"remove\" href=\"\"> <i class=\"fa fa-trash\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> </a></td> "; ?>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="postToDatabase(<?php echo substr($vals,0,-1); $vals=NULL; ?>);" class="add" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                                    </a>
                                </td>

                                               <?php echo "</tr>";

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                ?>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end arraytable col -->

                    <div class="col-3" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- form colum -->

                        <form name="form" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "POST">

                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($code_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Code:" id="code" name="code"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $code; ?>"/>
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $code_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($title_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Title:" id="title" name="title"  class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $title_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($number_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Inventory nr:" id="number" name="number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $number_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($value_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Inventory value:" id="value" name="value" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $value_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($retailValue_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Retail value:" id="retailvalue" name="retailvalue" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $retailValue; ?>" />
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $retailValue_err; ?></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" id="add"  value="Add" >
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div> <!-- end form colum -->
            </div> <!-- end array table, form row -->
                    </div>

            <script>
                $('#arraytable').on('click','tr a.remove',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });

                function postToDatabase(code, title,number,value,retailvalue){
                     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'index.php',
                    data:  "code=" + code + "&title=" + title + "&number=" + number + "&value=" + value + "&retailvalue=" + retailvalue,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $('#success_msg').show();
                    }
                });
                }
            </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```